# HyperSQL (HSQLDB): massive insert performance

Tags: java, performance, hsqldb, bulkinsert

I have an application that has to insert about 13 million rows of about 10 average length strings into an embedded HSQLDB. I've been tweaking things (batch size, single threaded/multithreaded, cached/non-cached tables, MVCC transactions, log_size/no logs, regular calls to `checkpoint`, ...) and it still takes 7 hours on a 16 core, 12 GB machine.

I chose HSQLDB because I figured I might have a substantial performance gain if I put all of those cores to good use but I'm seriously starting to doubt my decision.

Can anyone show me the silver bullet?

Comment: Going to hazard a guess (not a HSQLDB expert) and say the main blocker is on your IO (disk).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that since CPU percentage isn't exactly through the roof. Is there any benefit in doing batch inserts from multiple threads or should I stick to a single thread in this case?

Comment: Probably not, unless you can implement a SSD based solutiom.

Answer (score 5):

With CACHED tables, disk IO is taking most of the time. There is no need for multiple threads because you are inserting into the same table. One thing that noticably improves performance is the reuse of a single parameterized PreparedStatment, setting the parameters for each row insert.

On your machine, you can improve IO significantly by using a large NIO limit for memory-mapped IO. For example `SET FILES NIO SIZE 8192`. A 64 bit JVM is required for larger sizes to have an effect.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html

To reduce IO for the duration of the bulk insert use `SET FILES LOG FALSE` and do not perform a checkpoint until the end of the insert. The details are discussed here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_bulk_operations

UPDATE: An insert test with 16 million rows below resulted in a 1.9 GigaByte .data file and took just a few minutes on an average 2 core processor and 7200 RPM disk. The key is large NIO allocation.

```
connection time -- 47
complete setup time -- 78 ms
insert time for 16384000 rows -- 384610 ms -- 42598 tps
shutdown time  -- 38109
```

Comment: What operating system was this on? I'm finding that large batch inserts are reasonably fast on OS X and depressingly slow on Windows (on a variety of hardware configurations). Inserting 108,000 rows takes about 1 minute on a mid 2007 Mac Mini using the stock built-in hard drive. It takes about 15 minutes on late model non-virtualized Windows server, and longer than that (canceled after about 20 minutes) on an old 2006 non-virtual Dell 750 Windows server.

Comment: Never mind - problem turned out to be indexing-related. When I added an index the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

check what your application is doing. First things would be to look at resource utilization in taskmanager (or OS specific comparable) and visualvm.

Good candidates for causing bad performance:

- disk IO
- garbage collector

Answer (score 1):

[H2Database](http://www.h2database.com/) may give you slightly better performance than HSQLDB (while maintaining syntax compatibility).

In any case, you might want to try using a higher delay for syncing to disk to reduce random access disk I/O. (ie. `SET WRITE_DELAY <num>`)

Hopefully you're doing bulk `INSERT` statements, rather than a single insert per row. If not, do that if possible.

Depending on your application requirements, you might be better off with a key-value store than an RDBMS. (Do you regularly need to insert 1.3*10^7 entries?)

Your main limiting factor is going to be random access operations to disk. I highly doubt that anything you're doing will be CPU-bound. (Take a look at `top`, then compare it to `iotop`!)

Answer (score 0):

With so many records, maybe you could consider switching to a NoSQL DB. It depends on the nature/format of the data you need to store, of course.