# HSQLDB how to insert 1 million of records

Tags: insert, hsqldb

I am developing an GWT application.

In order to test my DataGrid I created a button which makes calls to my server.
When I hit on it 1 million of records should be inserted into the database.

I created an alias

```
CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC.GENERATENAME() RETURNS VARCHAR(32768) SPECIFIC GENERATENAME_10073 LANGUAGE JAVA NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL CALLED ON NULL INPUT EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:com.package.sql.Helper.generateName'
```

And created a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PUBLIC.GENERATE() SPECIFIC GENERATE_10073 LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA NEW SAVEPOINT LEVEL BEGIN ATOMIC DECLARE VAL_P BIGINT;TRUNCATE TABLE PUBLIC.CONTACT;SET VAL_P=1;LOOP_LABEL:WHILE VAL_P<=1000 DO INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CONTACT VALUES VAL_P,PUBLIC.GENERATENAME(),PUBLIC.GENERATENAME();SET VAL_P=VAL_P+1;END WHILE LOOP_LABEL;END
```

My table is a simple one

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,SECOND_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)
```

I tested and realized I can't insert 1M rows at once, or can I?

What is the best way to insert such a huge amount of data?

I am using HSQLDB version 2.2.4

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293517/hypersql-hsqldb-massive-insert-performance) you can find an answer to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use CREATE MEMORY TABLE, all the data is stored in memory. You may have to increase your Java heap allocation to store the data.

With file databases, you can use CREATE CACHED TABLE to reduce memory use.

Comment: But if I use cached tables I depend on I/O. Anyway I chose MEMORY tables and increased my Java heap space.

Comment: It's your choice which type of table is more suitable for your application.